# Choice function

Tags: general-topology

Is there any collection of set which has no choice function. Although from the definition it seems that every set has a choice function. But is it possible that some collection of set don't have a choice function. Well obviously when a set is empty. But I am thinking if it's true for non empty sets.

Comment: Do you know  the statement of the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @quasi  in choice function the sets does not need to  be disjoint

Comment: Do you think the Axiom of Choice doesn't apply to your question?

Comment: @quasi I am not saying that but if you have a collection of sets(not necessarily disjoint). Then through the axiom of choice u can proof the existence of choice function.

Comment: So if you agree that the Axiom of Choice guarantees the existence of a choice function for any nonempty collection of nonempty sets, and if you are accepting that axiom, then I don't understand what you are asking.